# Zoom in out mousedown

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho uma imagem SVG, como posso criar um pequeno zoom (aumentar a imagem) quando passo por cima com o mouse, e voltar ao seu tamanho quando saiu?

Tenho o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/37/

Comment: Já testaste `svg:hover{zoom:200%;}` ?

Comment: .img1:hover{zoom:200%;} não me funciona

Comment: Não porque isso é SVG, mas assim dá: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/39/, é isso que procuras?

Comment: Sim penso que seja isso, mas não me aparece a imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode obter o resultado desejado usando apenas css se utilizar medidas percentuais dentro do svg.

```css
svg {
  cursor: move;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
svg:active {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p>Clique na imagem para visualizar o efeito</p>
<svg>
  <image id=img1 data-type="img1" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/100x100" x=0 y=0 height=100% width=100% class="img1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Obrigado @patetico, mas queria sem ser com o click, apenas ao passar cm o mousse

Comment: o evento mousedown é pra clique, por isso eu deixei desse jeito, mas é só você trocar `svg:active` pra `svg:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Depende a qual zoom vc se refere.
Existem basicamente 2 tipos de ZOOM:

1. **Zoom Geométrico** -> A imagem exibida guarda as suas proporções físicas imutáveis.
2. **Zoom Semântico** -> As proporções da imagem se adapta à escala.

Veja esse link no [d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) para ver essas 2 definições na prática.

Dito isso, entende-se que para fazer Zoom In ou Zoom OUT numa IMAGEM SVG, você teria somente que dispara uma função que iria alterar as propriedades do svg de acordo com sua escala e de acordo com o tipo de ZOOM escolhido. SVG são funções matemáticas vetoriais que recebem parâmetros para gerar os contornos, diferentente de imagens raster que são pixels exemplo jpeg, jpg, png, entre outras. Nesse [Link](https://modassicmarketing.com/understanding-image-file-types) vc tem exemplo.

Infelizmente você não tem uma imagem SVG. O que vc tem é um stage SVG com uma imagem png (**favicon.png**) dentro desse stage. Veja o pedaço do seu código `<image id=img1 data-type="img1" xlink:href=/favicon.png`

Se você quer usar zomm in ou zoom out em imagens SGV, terá que gerar as imagens com as tags próprias, tais como:

1. Rectangle
2. Circle
3. Ellipse
4. Line
5. Relacionar o item
6. Polyline
7. Polygon
8. Path

Veja o link do [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html).

Se vc quiser continuar usando imagens raster e aplicar o zoom, mude as propriedades CSS. Veja o [exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).